# Appeal for my closed question

Tags: discussion

My question was closed for a reason, but I have since then edited the question and added an answer, that I consider quite valuable. So I wanted to give it a last chance of getting the spotlight before it goes forgotten forever:

[How to work when the folder \\appdata\local is locked because of security policy?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179910/how-to-work-when-the-folder-appdata-local-is-locked-because-of-security-policy)

Comment: Fyi closed questions that get edited are ([generally](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256567/120999)) automatically put into a queue for review to see if they are now fixed enough to re-open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very much off topic here, so no, it is not going to be reopened. It is not a security question as per our site scope - but a programming/development question as per @schroeder's comment.

If you think it is valuable, posting it on the relevant site will help to preserve it. You could look at the scope pages for Stack Overflow or Super User to see if it could work on one of them.

Comment: Posted on stack overflow, and guess what? Got downvoted as well. The topic is crossing both domains, and each site is bouncing the topic... as off topic. If nobody want to publish it, then I'm fine with it. But somebody in the future might have the same problem and not find the solution on a stack exchange site... which is sad, since somebody actually took the effort of publishing a solution

Comment: But that is absolutely fine. Some questions don't have a place on SE.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, the question and answer are not security-related, regardless of how valuable the solution is to you.

Unless there is a security angle, I think that it is rightly closed.